# Getting a realtime clock in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, datetime

I am trying to find a reliable solution with regards to measuring time in ios.
I'd like to show the passing of time with 1 sec precision. Exactly Like a stopwatch built in ios, but only seconds.
So far every solution I found, seems clunky, since it either uses polling with help of NStimer
or some love level C stuff.
The problem I have, is that "I" need to ask the system every time, what's the time. But if I should rely on NStimer which is nondeterminate, then my measurement is very unreliable.
Isn't there a delegate method called from the system that would update my time?
I guess If I enhanced the resolution of polling to 1 ns, it would be ok. But how should I implement it using low level C?

Comment: `NSTimer` is the traditional way to do this, and it works just fine for 1 sec resolution. Do you have any reason other than speculation to not use it? It would help if you demonstrated a specific problem you're having. Also, if you're really looking for a C-based solution, please re-tag your question.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me to implement it like this.I admin its a speculation but there is nothing wrong in thinking twice.  
If I set NStimer to a 1sec resolution to ask for actual time, it actualy will oscilate around the 1 sec interval. Sometimes it will ask in 0.9984 secs ..sometimes in 1.0055 secs..i will get results that will have to be rounded to nearest one sec..Ad this transformation to the work the result is => every second will last a different time. Won't I physically with my own eyes see, that the tempo is not constant?

Comment: How good do you think your brain is at distinguishing tens of milliseconds discrepancies? Not that good, I assure you. I've implemented graphical timers using `NSTimer` and it works just fine.

Comment: If I'll just cut the .004564 - tenths and hudnreths from every value then it may happen that the jump will not always be to 1 sec up, but it will "wait" and then jump 2 secs.
0.000
0.998 
1.999
2.998 
4.001

Comment: Not to mention that the actual GUI bits take an indeterminate number of milliseconds every time they need to be changed. I don't really understand your last comment.

Comment: If I understand correctly the NStimer is not the time provider, but only serves to repeat an action..here to ask the system for time.
So it asks for time very one second and I would display the results ..either rounded or only show the seconds.

Comment: Time is subjective... you know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are aiming for.  I can't figure out if you want a good way to query a high-resolution time, or if you want the system to call you back.

If the former, this is what I use for hi-res timer.

```
#import "mach/mach_time.h"

#define TICKS_TO_NANOS(_ticks_, _timebase_) (((_ticks_) * ((_timebase_).numer)) / ((_timebase_).denom))
#define NOW_IN_TICKS() (mach_absolute_time())
#define NOW_IN_NANOS(_timebase_) TICKS_TO_NANOS(NOW_IN_TICKS(), _timebase_)
```

If the latter, then you can **never** get a guaranteed callback timer.  Probably the most consistent timer callback will be to hook into CADisplayLink, but then you may not get that consistently if your graphics methods take too long.

You can try the system timers, but you won't get much guarantee there either.

Answer (score 1):

iOS devices only redraw the display 60 times per second (max), so any time accuracy beyond that will be invisible to the user.  You can use a CADisplayLink to call you each frame time, 60 times per second and ignore (return from) 59 of the calls.  But you will still have to poll one of the clocks (there's more than one) to check for drift between the display rate and the clocks.  And if your code does anything too long-winded in the UI run loop, you might miss a frame, so you have to check for that as well.